# Каким словом можно описать предвкушение?

Tags: лексикография

Стоит задача: нужно описать, как люди, играя в рулетку, по мере того как шарик замедляется, все громче и протяжнее говорят «ооо». Есть ли какой-нибудь глагол, чтобы описать одним словом само это действие, когда люди в предвкушении произносят это «ооо», при этом максимально его растягивая?

Comment: Самое ёмкое и точное слово, определяющие данную эмоцию - азарт.

Comment: Ну а глаголы: испытать азарт, войти в азарт, войти в раж.

Answer (score 2):

Предполагаю, что это может быть один из следующих глаголов:
предчувствовать, ожидать, надеяться, уповать, чаять, возбуждаться, нервничать, мандражировать, проявлять нетерпение, поддаваться азарту, войти в азарт, впадать в восторг, обольщаться надеждой, льстить себя надеждой, возлагать надежды (упования).
Сама же игра в рулетку невозможна без таких глаголов:
азартничать (проявлять азарт), азартиться (горячиться, выходить из себя, забываться [В. Даль]).

Максимально растянутое "ооо" обычно записывается с помощью **дефиса**.
— **О**-**о**, мамочки! О-о, ми-ылочки-ы! — Люба поворошила мои волосы... [Виктор Астафьев. Обертон (1995-1996)]
― **О**-**о**-**о**!.. ― в один голос разочарованно протянули Мила и Юрка. [Виталий Губарев. Трое на острове (1950-1960)]

Answer (score 0):

Есть, пожалуй, один глагол для описания такой ситуации. Но вообще есть правило: чем больше глаголов - тем точнее описание.

```
Люди нагнетали (обстановку/финал/исход) протяжным О-о-о!
Люди предваряли (обстановку/финал/исход) протяжным О-о-о!
Люди в предвкушении ожидали финала, произнося/растягивая О-о-о!
Люди ждали (исхода), предваряя протяжным О-о-о!
Люди ожидали (финала), в исступлении произнося О-о-о!
```

Answer (score 0):

Никого не хочу оспаривать, но лично я написал бы: *По мере того, как шарик замедляется, люди всё громче и протяжнее **стонут:** «О-о-о!»* (И не забыл бы запятую после *того* ;) )